# Modelling 2D gaussian in python using numpy

Tags: python, math, scipy, gaussian

I am trying to model a 2D gaussian function using the code below

```
import numpy as np

def gauss_2d(x, y, amp, x0, y0, sigma_x, sigma_y, theta):
    a_gauss_2d = ((np.cos(theta)**2) / (2*sigma_x**2)) + ((np.sin(theta)**2) / (2*sigma_y**2))
    b_gauss_2d = ((np.sin(2*theta)) / (2*sigma_x**2)) - ((np.sin(2*theta)) / (2*sigma_y**2))
    c_gauss_2d = ((np.sin(theta)**2) / (2*sigma_x**2)) - ((np.cos(theta)**2) / (2*sigma_y**2))

    term_1 = -1 * a_gauss_2d * ((x-x0) ** 2)
    term_2 = -1 * b_gauss_2d * (x-x0) * (y-y0)
    term_3 = -1 * c_gauss_2d * ((y-y0) ** 2)

    return amp* np.exp(term_1 + term_2 + term_3)


x_arr = np.linspace(1, 1000, 10000)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x_arr, x_arr)

theta_deg = 90
theta_rad = theta_deg * np.pi/180

z_data = gauss_2d(xx, yy, 1, 55, 55, 20, 20, theta_rad)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.contour(xx, yy, z_data, 50, cmap='winter')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want the gaussian to look something similar to this: [image: Expected Gaussian]

Comment: Remember the ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) policy article: what did you already do in terms of (re)searching and debugging to figure out where things are going wrong, even if you don't know how to fix what's wrong?

Comment: Why did you define your "2D Gaussian" with your own unjustified formula rather than any well sourced existing formula from e.g. wikipedia or wolfram?

Comment: Source for 2D gaussian: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.modeling.functional_models.Gaussian2D.html

Comment: Your "c" term has a different sign than the one in the formula on the page you shared.

Comment: Except "c" term error already mentioned, the "wrong" appearance is due to logarithmic scaling...